# Upload image folder in Laravel

Tags: laravel, file-upload

I am using below Trait.

```
public function safetyStore(Request $request ) {        
        $images = [];
        $files = $request->file('image');
        if($request->hasFile('image'))
        {
            foreach ($files as $file) {
                $file->store('users/helllo/messages');
                $images[] = $file->hashName();
            }
        }
}
```

Where is file uploading  ? Where can I find uploaded images ?

Comment: check the `storage/app/` directory

Comment: also are you sure `$request->hasFile('image')` works, from your code it seems like `image` field is an array or images, not a file by itself

Comment: Thanks @krisgjika. Yes, `images` field is an array. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Your images is in array form or want to upload multiple images**

```
public function safetyStore(Request $request)
{
    $images = [];
    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        foreach ($request->file('image') as $file) {
            $filename = $file->hashName();
            $file->storeAs('users/hello/messages', $filename);
            $images[] = $filename; 
        }
    }
}
```

**For Single Image You May Use This Code:**

```
function __construct()
{
  $this->userimagepath = 'images/users/';
}
public function safetyStore(Request $request)
{
   $safetyStore = new $safetyStore();
   if ($request->hasFile('image'))
   {
     $image = $request->file('image');
     $imageName = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
     $imageDestinationPath = public_path($this->safetyStoreImagePath);
     $image->move($imageDestinationPath, $imageName);
     $imageName = $this->safetyStoreImagePath . $imageName;
     $safetyStore->image = $imageName;
     $safetyStore->save();
   }
}
```

Happy Coding!